# Difference between two columns in two separate tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, difference

I have two tables in SQL Server:

```
 Product_Brought (
     Product_ID, Quantity_Brought,  ....
 )

 Product_Distribution (
    Product_ID,  Quantity_Sold, ....
 )
```

I want to compute the balance on hand from these two columns in these two tables by computing their difference. I have done something like this but it is returning something that doesn't make sense.

```
SELECT 
   DIFFERENCE((SELECT sum(Quantity_Brought) 
FROM 
   Product_Brought), 
   (SELECT sum(Quantity_Sold) FROM Product_Distribution))
```

Comment: Have a look on `DIFFERENCE` in BOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute SUM in sub queries and then do the substraction.

```
SELECT T1.TotalBrought - T2.TotalSold as BalanceOnHand
FROM
(SELECT SUM(Quantity_Brought) as TotalBrought
FROM Product_Brought
) T1,
(SELECT SUM(Quantity_Sold) as TotalSold
FROM Product_Distribution
) T2
```